# Get the date from a time string

Tags: php, zend-framework, date, datetime, zend-date

Is there a way to convert an input time string (ex: `01:13`) to a Zend date object, so that I store it later in a timestamp column in a Mysql database.

Examples:

If the current datetime is `2013-07-15 17:33:07` and the user inputs `18:05` the output should be `2013-07-15 18:05:00`.

If the current datetime is `2013-07-15 17:33:07` and the user inputs `02:09` the output should be `2013-07-16 02:09:00`. **Notice that since the time entered was lower than the current time, so it was treated as tomorrows time.**

I simply want to get the next point in time that satisfies the entered time. I'm open for solution using plain PHP or Zend_Date.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should compare the current time with the time entered by the user and create a DateTime object of either "today" or "tomorrow". DateTime accepts `strtotime()` relative time parameters.

Quick hack. Works as of today, 15.07.2013 23:58 local time:

```
$nextTime = new DateTime('today 18:10');
if ($nextTime < new DateTime('now')) { // DateTime comparison works since 5.2.2
    $nextTime = new DateTime('tomorrow 18:10');
}
echo $nextTime->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score -1):

here is working example for you just add your dynamic variable to check date with user inputs

You can use [mktime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to manage your date.

```
$input_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(18,05,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));

echo "current time".$current_time = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
echo "<br>User input is ".$input_date;

if(strtotime($current_time) > strtotime($input_date)){
    $input_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(18,05,0,date("m"),date("d")+1,date("Y")));

    echo "in";
}else{
    // nothing to do
}
echo "<br> result->".$input_date;
```

i hope it will sure solve your issue

Comment: You have a very subtle bug in your code. Calling `date()` multiple times for the same date will always use the current time of each of these function calls. You might end up calling the later `date()` just after the system time got to the next second, which might be the first second of a new day, a new month, or even a new year.

Comment: php execution is very fast then the other programming language so there want be any issue.

Comment: You are denying the bug that is there.

Comment: One call to `date()` takes 0,000030041 seconds on my machine. The second call for the same day WILL occur later. If the first call was made on 23:59:59,99998 hours, the second call will be made after midnight, on a new day. The chances are small, but do exist.

Comment: your answer consist latest php version function, if some one has old version this will work, but why downvote ?

Comment: Because your code has a bug. An evil bug. Nobody will notice. You do away with my arguments stating "PHP is fast enough". It is not. And by the way: My code works with any currently supported PHP versions. Which is 5.5, 5.4 and 5.3. I just updated to also support 5.2.2 - available now for more than 6 years.

Comment: ohh ok i am agree, :(

Comment: will please send me link, how can we check php script execution time ? pls dont mind

Comment: I don't think you get it. I'll stop wasting time now explaining.

Comment: i will appreciate you if you will help me to learn this things